# Count by unique key

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[
  {
    assigned_user:{
            name:'Paul',
            id: 34158
        },
    doc_status: "processed"
  },
  {
      assigned_user:{
            name:'Simon',
            id: 48569
        },
    doc_status: "processed"
  },
  {
      assigned_user:{
            name:'Simon',
            id: 48569
        },
    doc_status: "processed"
  }
];
```

Let's say I have the above array.

I am looking for a function that can count how many times we encounter each unqiue user, and then push the result in another array:

So, I want to get something like this:

```
[
  {
    user:"Simon",
    count: 2
  },
  {
    user: "Paul",
    count: 1
  }
];
```

Any ideas?

I tried to solve by taking all the unique users and then count the times each of them appear in my array but I couldn't make it out.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: I'm thinking of lodash' [xorBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#xorBy). Dunno...

Answer (score 0):

***Ecmascript5*** solution (`Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Array.prototype.map()` functions):

```js
var arr = [
        {assigned_user:{name:'Paul',id: 34158},doc_status: "processed"}, {assigned_user:{name:'Simon',id: 48569},doc_status: "processed"}, {assigned_user:{name:'Simon',id: 48569},doc_status: "processed"}
    ];

var counts = arr.reduce(function (r, o) {
    var user = o.assigned_user.name;     // getting reference to username
    (r[user])? ++r[user] : r[user] = 1;  // accumulating username occurrences
    return r;
}, {}),
    // costructing the final structure `user`:`count`
    result = Object.keys(counts).map(function (k) {
        return {user: k, count: counts[k]};
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [{assigned_user:{name:'Paul',id: 34158},doc_status: "processed"},{assigned_user:{name:'Simon',id: 48569},doc_status: "processed"},{assigned_user:{name:'Simon',id: 48569},doc_status: "processed"}];

const b = [...new Set(a.map(x => x.assigned_user.name))]
 .map(x => Object.assign({}, {user: x, count: a.filter(e => e.assigned_user.name === x).length}))
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(b, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table as reference to the user's count.

Then iterate over the given array and check if the hash table contains the user object. If not create one and push the object to the result set.

Increment the user's count at the hash table's object.

Later, you could sort the result array for top count at top.

```js
var data = [{ assigned_user: { name: 'Paul', id: 34158 }, doc_status: "processed" }, { assigned_user: { name: 'Simon', id: 48569 }, doc_status: "processed" }, { assigned_user: { name: 'Simon', id: 48569 }, doc_status: "processed" }],
    count = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var user = a.assigned_user.name;
            if (!hash[user]) {
                hash[user] = { user: user, count: 0 };
                r.push(hash[user]);
            }
            hash[user].count++;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);


count.sort(function (a, b) { return b.count - a.count; });
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/("name":)"\w+(?=")/` to get `"name"` property and value from object, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/["]|name":/g` to remove property name; `for..of` loop and `Array.prototype.find()` to check is property exists in object, if not `.push()` object to array, else increment `"count"` property

```js
let data = [{
    assigned_user: {
      name: 'Paul',
      id: 34158
    },
    doc_status: "processed"
  },
  {
    assigned_user: {
      name: 'Simon',
      id: 48569
    },
    doc_status: "processed"
  },
  {
    assigned_user: {
      name: 'Simon',
      id: 48569
    },
    doc_status: "processed"
  }
];

let res = [];
for (let user of JSON.stringify(data).match(/("name":)"\w+(?=")/g).map(user => user.replace(/["]|name":/g, ""))) {
  if (!res.find(({user: _name}) => _name === user))
    res.push({user, count: 1})
  else
    ++res.find(({user: _name}) => _name === user).count
}

console.log(res);
```